# Is it possible to retrieve a doctrine repository in symfony by providing an interface name?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I use the doctrine orm resolve_target_entities config to map interfaces to actual class implementations (e.g. WalletInterface -> Wallet). Now it would be helpful to retrieve a repository of the actual linked class like this:

```
$repository = $em->getRepository(WalletInterface::class)
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: What about the case where multiple classes implement the `WalletInterface`?

Comment: I guess it is a 1-to-1 mapping between Interface and concrete class? E.g. I am writing a payment bundle and the Wallet class already exists here -  the project bundle extends the Wallet and I want to get the repository of the config-defined class in the code of the payment bundle. Documentation says: "It means that in your bundle you are able to use an interface or abstract class in your mappings and expect correct mapping to a concrete entity at runtime." http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html

Comment: Somewhat sadly the resolver is not going to help you here.  Be kind of nice if it did but the resolver functionality is really too limited to be of much use.  You could probably hack up something which looks at the doctrine metadata but it would probably not be very pretty.